# SQL Create a table with hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

Would someone help out with structuring the table and querying? Thank you for your time!

Suppose below is a record of the phones I owned:

```
ID    | Object            | Start Month | End Month 
1     | Phone 1           |     1       |   3      
2     | Phone 1 OS Update |     2       |   3      
3     | Phone 2           |     4       |   5
4     | Phone 3           |     6       |   7

Desired result
Query: Month = 2; Return ID = 1,2 (Logic: Phone 1 with its OS update)
Query: Month = 4; Return ID = 3 (Logic: Phone 2 replaces Phone 1 and update)
Query: Month = 6; Return ID = 4 (Logic: Phone 3 replaces Phone 2)
```

Right now, I am making a separate table with months printed out like the following.

```
ID       | Object            | Month    
1        | Phone 1           |     1           
1        | Phone 1           |     2        
2        | Phone 1 OS Update |     2          
1        | Phone 1           |     3 
2        | Phone 1 OS Update |     3       
3        | Phone 2           |     4      
3        | Phone 2           |     5   
4        | Phone 3           |     6 
4        | Phone 3           |     7   

SELECT [ID]
FROM Table
WHERE MONTH = 2
```

I also add an extra column with the id of the next "superior" phone. Can this table be generated automatically without manually inserting each line for each month? If this table is inefficient, how can I structure a table and then query?

```
ID       | Object            | Month | Superior Object ID     
1        | Phone 1           |     1 |   3            
1        | Phone 1           |     2 |   3         
2        | Phone 1 OS Update |     2 |   1          
1        | Phone 1           |     3 |   3  
2        | Phone 1 OS Update |     3 |   1       
3        | Phone 2           |     4 |   4       
3        | Phone 2           |     5 |   4   
4        | Phone 3           |     6 |   NULL   
4        | Phone 3           |     7 |   NULL
```

Comment: If you use syntax like `SELECT [ID]` then you're using SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: With the first table can't you use `WHERE month BETWEEN [Start Month] AND [End Month]`?

Comment: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: I am trying to query the phone I used for a particular month. I wouldn't know [Start Month] and [End Month] because I don't even remember the phone associated with these dates.

Comment: You don't need to know `Start Month` and `End Month`, that's in the table. `month` is the input.

Comment: Do you mean SELECT [ID] FROM Table WHERE '2' BETWEEN [Start Month] AND [End Month]?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Barmar  Thank you! It worked! So I have a follow-up question: The end goal is to generate a report of all the months, each month with associated objects. So I am writing a stored procedure which would desire a data table like the second table above. How would I generate the second table? Is creating a class for each phone/update possible in SQL?

Comment: Just loop through all the months, perform the query, and insert the results into the table.

Comment: @Barmar Got it! Thank yoU!